# Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties"

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am working on react project. It was working properly. But now whenever I start npm. It gives me error:

```
$ react-scripts start
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.18.45/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\xampp\htdocs\SkyHi\Staah\staah-instant-site\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index.es.js
Error: [BABEL] C:\xampp\htdocs\SkyHi\Staah\staah-instant-site\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-svg-core\index.es.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SkyHi\\Staah\\staah-instant-site\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\dependencies.js$0")
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

I am using `yarn`.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Does your package.json include @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties?

Comment: Yes. It is there. For temporary. I have uninstalled node_module directory and reinstall it. But I believe this not a proper way to fix this. Their may be correct way to tackle with this issue. Hope this post will help someone from spending time to find solution. Hope someone will answer it correctly.

Comment: Same problem here, tried everything, but no solution. (even remove node_module didn't solve the issue)